# Casting "as? Int" in Swift yields different results for different numbers

Tags: ios, swift, casting, null

I have an iOS app that worked fine, until at some point it started crashing on a `nil` value for a certain number.

After doing some tests in my code I managed to boil it down to the following piece of code that yields an output that does not make sense to me at all:

```
let tc: AnyObject? = jsonObject["times_completed"]
let pos: AnyObject? = jsonObject["position"]

println("TC FROM JSON \(tc)")
println("POS FROM JSON \(pos)")

println("TC TYPE: \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(tc))")
println("POS TYPE: \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(pos))")

let tcInt = tc as? Int
let posInt = pos as? Int

println("TC TYPE: \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(tcInt))")
println("POS TYPE: \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(posInt))")

println("TC: \(tcInt)")
println("POS: \(posInt)")
```

Output:

```
TC FROM JSON Optional(648)
POS FROM JSON Optional(6)

TC TYPE: Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>
POS TYPE: Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>

TC TYPE: Swift.Optional<Swift.Int>
POS TYPE: Swift.Optional<Swift.Int>

TC: nil
POS: Optional(6)
```

As you can see we have two `Int`s here, from which one ends up being `nil` (TC) and the other one end up holding the expected value (POS).

Since the code has always worked, I suspect that the number itself may be a problem (too high?).

Casting the Int in a different way helps, like so:

```
let tcInt = tc?.integerValue
```

But that would mean I have to resubmit my app, which will take some time. I would like to avoid that, maybe by (temporarily) changing the values for `times_completed`

Can anybody explain what happens here? Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

Please also check a piece of the JSON below. It seems that it is not a string, but a number. The key *is* a string, but would that matter?

```
...
position = 6;
slug = "my-quiz";
"times_completed" = 648;
...
```

Comment: Please check my update to see that it does not appear to be a string. Also: this code worked before.

Comment: It turned out that the backend was changed without informing me or testing. It had been changed to a string after all. I suppose the "pretty" printing in the console gave me the wrong impression. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `jsonObject["times_completed"]` is a string and not a number.

And because `.integerValue` works for you proves it because its an `NSString` property.

And casting a `String` to an `Int` will crash.

You can also do it like this:

```
let tcInt = (jsonObject["times_completed"] as? String)?.toInt()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `jsonObject["times_completed"]` is returning a String value and treating String like an Int in `let tcInt = tc as? Int` is causing a problem.
Note that

```
var a : AnyObject? = 10
var b : AnyObject? = "10"

println(a)
println(b)
```

prints Optional(10) in both cases. Try casting it as String and check the results `let tcInt = tc as? String`. If thats correct don't worry, your app isn't crashing because of your fault and maybe something in backend changed

Answer (score 0):

The result of nil is probably because `jsonObject["times_completed"]` can not be cast to Int.
Try to cast it to String or other Type.

```
if let tcStr = jsonObject["times_completed"] as? String {
    // string...
}
```